# HealthChecks in DropWizard 0.8.0-rc1

Tags: database, dropwizard, health-monitoring

I am following the documentation to create a healthcheck for my dropwizard application for database connectivity. I wanted to know how does the healthScript get a Database class? What do I need to import in order to use teh Database class mentioned in the Documentation?

http://dropwizard.io/0.8.0-rc1/docs/manual/core.html#health-checks

Comment: You can check this example application that uses ElasticSearch: https://github.com/spinscale/dropwizard-blog-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/services/BlogService.java#L80

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an example providing a general idea of what can be accomplished with healthchecks. There isn't a concrete `Database` class that you can import. The actual healthcheck would depend on your choice of DB connection: [JDBI](http://dropwizard.io/0.8.0/docs/manual/jdbi.html) or [Hibernate](http://dropwizard.io/0.8.0/docs/manual/hibernate.html). Dropwizard also easily allows you to define your own DAO for whatever vendor / protocol you need. And if you read through that documentation you'll see that those database objects are [configured just like everything else](http://dropwizard.io/0.8.0/docs/manual/core.html#configuration) - with YAML.

Note that you can upgrade to the [0.8.0 release](http://dropwizard.io/0.8.0/docs/manual/core.html#health-checks) instead of the release candidate.